# Does QueryDosDevice and IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUM treat LUNs as separate devices?

Tags: winapi, usb, scsi

Can someone confirm whether `QueryDosDevice()` and `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER` considers `LUN`s on the same physical USB storage device as a single device, or is each LUN considered as a separate device?

For example, if I have a USB thumb drive that has multiple `LUN`s, and each LUN has been allocated a logical DOS "letter", such as `C`:, `D:`, etc, if I call `QueryDosDevice()` will it return the same `DeviceName` for all the `LUN`s? Or will each `LUN` have a different `DeviceName`?

Similarly, if I use `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER` for each of the `LUN`s, will the returned `DeviceNumber` be the same for all the `LUN`s?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: AFAICT, USB doesn't necessarily work with LUNs like that. The USB spec has a mass storage class. Windows understands partitions on USB mass storage devices, which means that a USB thumb drive with 2 drive letters can have (1) one mass storage volume with 2 partitions or (2) two mass storage volumes, both unpartioned.